# CodeIgniter - Delete multiple rows and reorder next records in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to delete multiple rows and then reordering the next database records.
ELDI_Order it's not an autoincrement.

### This is my MODEL for DELETING ONE RECORD

```
public function delete_one_record($id)
    {

        $this->db->select('ELDI_Order');
        $this->db->where("ELDI_Id", $id);
        $eldi_order = $this->db->get('elem_diccio')->row()->ELDI_Order

        // Delete that record
        $this->db->delete('elementos_diccionario', array('ELDI_Id' => $id));

        // Reorder ELDI_Order for the rest of the records
        $this->db->set('ELDI_Order', 'ELDI_Order-1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('ELDI_Order >', $eldi_order);
        $this->db->update('elem_diccio');    
    }
```

### MODEL for DELETING MULTIPLE RECORDS

```
 function eliminar_varios_elementos_diccionario($ids)
    {
        $this->db->where_in('ELDI_Id', explode(",", $ids));
        $this->db->delete('elem_diccion');

        // Code for reordering
    }
```

For example, if I delete rows 2 and 8 (the 4th) I want to substract 1 to the column ELDI_Order of prueba_3 because it moved "1 place", and 2 from prueba_5 because it "moved" 2 places because I deleted 2 records.
[image: Example]

[image: Example2]

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: can you show your view table

Comment: What do you mean with "view table"? Sorry, my english is very limited >.<

Comment: change `serial no` in your view using foreach loop

Comment: I edited my question and added the view (the tbody), I don't know if that's what you ask...

Comment: Deleted the view because I need it to be done on the database, not visually.

Comment: Does you `delete_one_record` work as expected? If it does then its fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your `delete_one_record` function and a foreach. I can't see a way to inefficiently reorder multiple items at a time - so its not too bad to do them individually.

```
function eliminar_varios_elementos_diccionario($ids)
    {
       if (!is_array($ids)) {
           $ids = explode(",", $ids);
       }
       foreach ($ids as $id) {
           $this->delete_one_record(intval($id)); // assummed function is in same model
       }
    }
```

Suggestion: think about using transactions.

Comment: My multidelete works just fine, it deletes the records I choose with checkboxes, the problem is that I need to edit that columns (ELDI_Order) at the same time depending on the number of deletions.

Comment: there is no reason for your multidelete  not to work as expected. i'm just saying you will incur almost the same amount of database debt with reordering since it will have to be done systematically e.g. one by one. so you might as well just use your delete one record function in a loop.

Comment: think about it: there is no clean way to reorder multiple shifts affecting other items in 1 query. and thus you will just end up looping anyways using multiple queries

Comment: I'm trying your solution @Alex but for some reason foreach doesn't work... It deletes nothing, it's weird --- Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `print_r($ids)` before foreach; what is there?

Comment: ["322", "325"] it gives the correct ids, but does not delete. If I write directly $ids = [323, 327]; it deletes correctly.

Comment: hmm check update. i suppose if you `var_dump($ids)` its a string not an array

Comment: I did a "mix" with your solution and it works now! Thanks mate! --- My code (controller) : --- public function eliminar_varios_elementos_diccionario()
    {
        $ids =  explode(",", $this->input->post('ids'));
        
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            $this->mod_diccionarios->delete_one_record($id);
        }
        /* $this->mod_diccionarios->eliminar_varios_elementos_diccionario($ids); */
 
        echo json_encode(['success'=>"Item Deleted successfully."]);
    }

Comment: please check into transactions. its only 3 lines of code! cheers